# Remove or hide div if undifined/null or empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which can display information based up on  url and save this information: [moskah.nl](http://moskah.nl)

The problem is that if you would click the button without giving url than the script will give an empty div. Just reload the page and you will see it will still be there.

What can I do in Jquery in order to remove or hide these emty divs on document ready?

Comment: Example of code of how you're accessing the URL to load content?

Comment: @David Hi, its not my script but I believe Its var Display found over here: http://moskah.nl/preview.js  (to big to place here)

Comment: doest it return empty divs? or divs with blank space?

Comment: it returns divs with someTag="undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You can try `$("div:empty").remove();` or `$("div:empty").hide();`

Since there is no code provided, I am not really sure if this is what you want.

Comment: Thats seems to hide the div, but it hides all the divs not just the empty once (the code is on the url in my question moskah.nl.....)

Comment: no, it just hides empty div because of the :empty selector. can you try it once?

Comment: I did try it check it out moskah.nl

Comment: hmm.. i just tried this function in the chrome console. it worked! $('div').length ->
37;
$('div:empty').remove();
...
$('div').length -> 
33

Comment: Writing $('div').length -> 37; Is something entirely different

Comment: i was counting divs before and after remove.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your div has classname "item", then you have loop through each div and check which one is empty and hide them.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#feed').children('div').each(function() {
        if(($(this).attr('data-url')=='undefined'))
        $(this).hide();
    });
     //for first div only special check:-
      if(($('.item.first').attr('data-url')=='undefined'))
        $('.item.first').hide();

    });
```

Comment: @YOUSS :- SEE THE UPDATED CODE ..IT WILL WORK

Comment: It doesnt work..I think my divs are called '.item' and they are located in '#feed' So I tried '.item' and '#feed div'. Nothing works. I think the problem is that the divs are created dynamicly

Comment: it does not matter whether your divs are static or dynamic, simply you have to check that on your page if there is div having classname '.item' and it is empty ,then you have to hide them..and the above piece of code should work certainly..

Comment: If you are using Chrome: 1) Right click mouse and inspect element(empty div) 2) You will see the div has a class="item" 3) If I copy youre code and change "mydivclass" in to ".item" and load page nothing happen. Which means your code doesn't work.. If you don't believe me you can look at the page: moskah.nl

Comment: @Youss  i checked your code and edited my answer accordingly ..now check and let me know

Comment: Please go to moskah.nl and look at the source code, as you can see I have implemented your code, it still doesn't work

Comment: @Youss i am sorry ..i forgot something in my code...can you please check with updated one ...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

You can use .is() function after loading the div.

```
if( $('#leftmenu').is(':empty') ) {
    // REMOVE
```

You can also use the length property:

```
if( $('#leftmenu:empty').length ) {
    // REMOVE
```

Or you can trim and then check.

```
if( !$.trim( $('#leftmenu').html() ).length ) {
    // REMOVE
```

Please let me know if this works. Implement and let me know.

> EDITED

USE

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('div:empty').remove(); });
```

I tried it in Firefox. It worked.

Comment: Please note the divs are created dynamicly see the source http://moskah.nl/preview.js

Comment: leftmenu is the name of the div you try to hide.

Comment: Let me try with the preview.js perspective

Comment: Please do because Im out of ideas:)

Comment: Just one more clarification from your end. I checked and this is the div that is loading empty right ? <div class="clear"></div>

Comment: Yes I think so (but Im not sure..)

Comment: In Preview.js >> What is the use of : //Clear div.
      Ext.DomHelper.append('display',{
          tag : 'div',
          class : 'clear',
      }); It is appending Clear div at the end

Comment: Its not my script...maybe a mistake??

Comment: I sure hope so.. As it seems the <div class="clear"> is added by that code. Can you comment it and check if that solves your problem ?

Comment: I removed the code       //Clear div.
      Ext.DomHelper.append('display',{
          tag : 'div',
          class : 'clear',
      });  It doesnt seem to help, The divs are still added

Comment: prashanth Already provided this answer 1 hour ago...It remove ALL divs, go to moskah.nl to see result...

Comment: I saved the page and tried the code in there.. the Script tag.. and it  is just removing the empty divs.. the problem with your code is it is showing two errors on the browser due to which it is not loading properly. at the time of edit there must be something very wrong.

Comment: @Youss, I think I got the problem. When you are removing the empty div. It removes another div goes by the id='header'. which removes the HTML characterset specs and hence the javascript is not loading. If you want to make it work make sure that while removing id='header' div is not removed or excluded while removing.

Comment: Final solution I can give is this.. in the html part delete "<div id="header"></div>" and paste "<div id="header"> </div>" instead (without quotes) along with the "$(document).ready(function() { $('div:empty').remove(); }); " .... It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do some data validation to stop the form submitting empty data instead of just hiding it? Something like this

```
$('#id_submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

$('#id_submit').click(function(event){
    if ($('#id_status').val().length > 0) {
        $('#id_submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else
    {
    event.PreventDefault()
    }
});
```

Comment: This code doesn't submit anything. I already have a code that kinda does this, but I really would like to (at least) know how to remove emty divs (because Im planning to do other stuff)